# how to connect pact-broker docker container to local postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, docker, redhat, pact-broker

My dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby24:0.9.26

ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/pact_broker/
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY container /
RUN gem update --system
# USER app

COPY pact_broker/config.ru pact_broker/Gemfile pact_broker/Gemfile.lock $APP_HOME
# Update system gems for:
# https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/08/29/multiple-vulnerabilities-in-rubygems/
RUN gem install bundler && \
    cd $APP_HOME && bundle install --deployment --without='development test'
COPY pact_broker/ $APP_HOME/
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
```

How would I make this container use a local installation of postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

If on MAC OS -

By default Postgres works on localhost and if you haven't done any changes with that then it must be localhost.

Our case is to connect Postgres with our container of pact-broker means a container will interact with our local.

So instead of "localhost" define your host as "docker.for.mac.localhost", It should work.

- **Note:** if you are on diff OS other then MAC and their must something same like this you can check for that like "docker.for.win.localhost" for windows*

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to access `PostgreSQL` on host from an above container:

**1.** Only on `<HOST_IP>:<PostgreSQL_PORT>`, if docker container is started in a bridge network:

```
docker run -d <image_name>
```

`PostgreSQL` should be bound to `<HOST_IP>` or `0.0.0.0` (which includes `<HOST_IP>`).

**2.** On `<HOST_IP>:<PostgreSQL_PORT>` (if `PostgreSQL` is bound to `<HOST_IP>` or `0.0.0.0`) and `localhost:<PostgreSQL_PORT>`, if docker container is started in  the host network:

```
docker run --network host -d <image_name>
```

By default `PostgreSQL` is bound to `localhost`, so the second way is an all-purpose solution.